# Birational invariants and fundamental groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

In pondering [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32938/surfaces-in-mathbbp3-with-isolated-singularities) MO question and people's efforts to answer it, and recalling also something that I learned in my youth about using Morse theory ideas to prove some results of Lefschetz in the complex case, I seem to have learned two things -- things that I suppose are absorbed in the cradle by those who study algebraic geometry as opposed to learning it by osmosis -- or maybe I haven't got them quite right. Anyway:

(1) Blowing up a surface at a smooth point does not change the fundamental group, and (therefore ?) the fundamental group of a smooth projective surface is a birational invariant.

(2) Surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ are simply connected, and more generally for a set $X\subset\mathbb P^n$ defined by a single homogeneous equation of degree $>0$ the pair $(\mathbb P^n,X)$ is at least $(n-1)$-connected. That is, the relative homotopy groups and therefore the relative homology groups vanish up through dimension $n-1$.)

(This is all over the complex numbers.)

Is this correct? And, taking off from (1), what are some other simple statements about invariants from homotopy theory that are birational invariants? And what are the first things to know about birational invariants that do not come from topology?

EDIT  I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Comment: Yes for (1) and (2). So far so good! Dimensions of spaces cooked out of the holomorphic tangent bundle -- specfically spaces of $p$-forms, and spaces of sections of tensors powers of  $K=\det T_X^*$ (called plurigenera) -- are birational invariants that algebraic geometers love. These are not homotopy invariants in general. Hope that helps.

Comment: And if a surface $S\subset\mathbb P^2$ has just one singular point $x$ then is there some rule for describing the fundamental group of $S-x$ in terms of the (formal isomorphism class of?) the singularity? If the thing is formally like a cone on a smooth plane curve, do you always get the fundamental group of that curve?

Comment: Tom -- cones over curves are simply-connected as well.

Comment: I suspect Tom's questions were all concerning $S-x$. I don't have
answer, however.

Comment: Yes. I see that surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$, no matter how singular, are simply connected. I see that when you remove a smooth point the surface remains simply connected. I wondered what systematic statements there might be about what the fundamental group is when you remove a singular point.

Comment: Tom, I assume that you are aware of Milnor's classical book, "Singular points of complex hypersurfaces"?

Comment: I've heard of it, that's all.

Comment: If $S \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a cone over a smooth plane curve $B$ with vertex $x$, then $S-x$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-bundle over $B$, so we have  
$\pi_1(S-x)=\pi_1(B)$ by the homotopy sequence of a fibration: 

$\{1\}=\pi_1(\mathbb{C}) \to \pi_1(S-x) \to \pi_1(B) \to \{1\}$

Comment: Yes. In this case both the complement of the point and the blown-up surface have $\pi_1(B)$ as fundamental group. I wondered about other cases. Your Keum-Zhang answer shows that the story is not simple!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would like to mention one more homotopy invariant of smooth projective varieties that is also a birational invariant. If $X$ is a smooth projective variety, then the torsion subgroup $T(X)$ of ${\rm H}^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is a birational invariant. This is explained in the beautiful paper "Some elementary examples of unirational varieties which are not rational" by Artin-Mumford, which starts exactly outlining a "homotopical" approach to showing that there exist unirational threefolds that are not rational. Their homotopic criterion is that rational varieties $X$ have trivial group $T(X)$ and they construct unirational varieties with non-trivial two-torsion in such group, showing that these are examples of unirational, non rational varieties.

Finally, for surfaces the quantity $K^2+\rho$ is a birational invariant, where $K^2$ is the self intersection of the canonical divisor class on $X$ and $\rho$ is the rank of the N\'eron-Severi group of $X$). This is not too deep, as it is immediate knowing that a birational map of surfaces is a composition of blow ups and blow downs of smooth points (which for surfaces is quite easy!) and the above quantity is obviously invariant under a blow up. The reason for mentioning it, is that the N\'eron-Severi group can be defined in terms of Hodge theory, which, while not entirely homotopical, certainly has a homotopical feel to it. Moreover, many birational invariants are defined using Hodge structures, so it seemed useful to point it out!

Answer (score 16):

1. True since topologically blowing up a point is taking a connected sum with $\overline{ \mathbf{P}^2(\mathbf{C})}$.
2. True for smooth surfaces (generally, for smooth projective hypersurfaces, but it suffices to prove this for surfaces; I will try to give more details a bit later). If $X$ is a smooth hypersurface of $\mathbf{P}^n$, then moreover the homology map induced by the inclusion is an iso in degree $\leq n-2$ and is surjective in degree $n-1$ (this follows from the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem as given e.g. in Griffiths-Harris, chapter 1).

upd Here is a sketch of the proof of the fact that smooth projective hypersurfaces are simply connected. If we have a positive holomorphic line bundle $L$ on a complex analytic manifold $M$ (i.e. a line bundle whose Chern class is represented by $-i$ times a positive linear combination of $dz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_j$'s) and a smooth section $s$ of $L$ then we can equip the bundle with a hermitian metric so that the curvature will be $-2\pi i$ times the "positive" representative of the Chern class. We can then consider the function $\log |s|^2$ on the complement of a tubular neighborhood of the zero locus $V$ of $s$. A local calculation shows that at each singular point the Hessian of this function has at least $\dim M$ negative eigenvalues. I.e. $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $V$ with some cells of dimension $\geq n$ attached to it. For more details see Griffiths-Harris, chapter 1, Lefschetz hyperplane theorem.

Comment: Is the fundamental group a birational invariant of smooth projective varieties in arbitrary dimension? I think that it follows from the nontrivial theorem that every birational isomorphism of smooth projective varieties factors into a product of blow-ups and blow-downs with smooth centers, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1896232

Comment: Victor -- I would say yes since blowing up is informally speaking removing a subvariety and inserting the projectivized normal bundle instead. This should not change the fundamental group.

Comment: Victor -- is the following less nontrivial? Every birational iso between smooth projective varieties is a composition of blowdowns and their inverses, where "blowdown" is in the broad sense of proper morphism between smooth projective varieties, isomorphism in a nonempty open set. If f:X-->Y is a blowdown in that sense then there is a codimension 2 closed set C in Y such that its preimage C' in X has codim 1 and f gives an iso X-C'-->Y-C. For codimension reasons pi_1(X-C')-->pi_1(X) is surjective and pi_1(Y-C)-->pi_1(Y) is iso, and this implies pi_1(X)-->pi_1(Y) is iso.

Comment: In SGA1 it is proved that the fundamental group is a birational invariant of smooth projective varieties over any algebraically closed field.  It rests on Zariski-Nagata purity, if I rememeber correctly. No need for deep results on factorization of birational maps, just that they're isoms away from codim 2 stuff. 

Comment: Brian, "over any alg closed field" seems to imply that the statement concerns not the topological fundamental group itself, but its profinite completion. Can you, please, clarify?

Comment: Victor, indeed the argument in sga1 concerns the profinite group.  But I think it should adapt to the topological one. The main point is that a proper birational map between smooth projective varieties is an isomorphism away from Zariski-closed sets of codimension > 1 in the source and target, so the issue is to check that the topological fundamental group is unaffected by removing such closed sets.  That sounds quite reasonable, thinking in terms of real codimensions and topological loops.  Is there a subtlety?  (I haven't thought it through in a while, so maybe I miss something?) 

Comment: BCnrd -- yes, removing a polyhedron $X$  of real codimension $>2$  from a smooth manifold does not affect the fundamental group for transversality reasons: not only we can push any loop away from $X$, but any homotopy between loops as well. 

Comment: algori, are Zariski-closed sets in a smooth variety adequate substitutes for "polyhedrons" to make the argument work? I was mainly worried about handling horrendous singularities in such a closed subset. (Well, not so much "worried" as unsure of the rigorous details in the presence of bad singularities; I assume it is ultimately all ok by some standard facts in the topology of complex algebraic varieties and their subvarieties.) 

Comment: Brian, algori: Thank you, that is much easier! Tom: If I understand your argument correctly, $\pi_1(Y)$ surjects to $\pi_1(X)$ for a single blowdown, but supposing you have surjections in both directions, how do you conclude that they are isomorphisms? The problem is that we don't know whether $\pi_1(Y)$ is cohopfian. 

Comment: BCnrd -- given a complex algebraic variety $X$ and a closed subvariety $Y$, the Lojasiewicz's theorem implies that one can triangulate $X$ so that $Y$ is a subpolyhedron. I think a similar result should hold for $X$ and $Y$ complex analytic (or even real analytic). In the smooth case there are pathologies: any closed subset of a smooth manifold is the zero locus of a smooth function.

Comment: BCnrd -- I am surely digging my own grave here, but I think "a proper birational map between smooth projective varieties is an isomorphism away from Zariski-closed sets of codimension > 1 in the source and target" is not really what you had in mind. (Eg: blowing up a smooth point in a smooth variety.)

Comment: @Artie: whoops, I garbled what I meant to say.  The correct statement is that since a rational map between smooth proper varieties is defined away from closed set of codim $> 1$, insensitivity of the topological fundamental group to removing any such closed sets (which algori justified in the topological case) implies that it's *functorial* in such *dominant* rational maps (hence takes such birat'l maps to *isoms*) provided any dense Zariski-open $U \subset X$ induces surjection on top. fund. groups. Surjectivity holds because loops push away from $X-U$ of real codim $\ge 2$. QED

Comment: BCnrd: The statement "the pair $(N,N-M)$ is at least $(n-m-1)$-connected if $N$ is an $n$-manifold and the subset $M$ is $m$-dimensional" can be made precise and true in at least two ways: (1) piecewise linear manifold and piecewise linear subset (which includes smooth manifold and smoothly triangulable subset), or (2) smooth manifold and subset which is a finite or countable union of images of smooth maps whose domains are at most $m$-dimensional manifolds. Either of these can be applied to the complex algebraic (or analytic) case.

Comment: Dear Tom:  Oh, of course, stratify $X - U$ by successive smooth parts and work up from removing the lowest-dimensional part to the whole thing.  Thanks. 

Comment: Victor, I meant: given birational iso between $d$-dim $X$ and $Y$, both smooth projective. Let $Z\subset X\times Y$ be closure of graph of iso between dense opens. Show that both $Z\to X$ and $Z\to Y$ induce iso of $\pi_1$. In $X$ there is $A$ of dim $\le d-2$ such that preimage of $X-A$ in $Z$ maps isomorphically to $X-A$. Let $B$ be preimage of $A$. Certainly $X-A\to X$ induces iso of $\pi_1$ since $X$ is smooth. Even if $Z$ is smooth, the same argument only gives $Z-B\to Z$ inducing surjection of $\pi_1$ (because $dim B=d-1$). But that's enough; $\pi_1(Z-B)\to \pi_1(Z)\to \pi_1(X)$ is iso.

Comment: But $Z$ might not be smooth. So normalize it and then use Zariski's Main Thm to get $\pi_1(Z-B)\to\pi_1(Z)$ surjective?

Answer (score 6):

The paper of Keum and Zhang

"Fundamental groups of open K3 surfaces, Enriques surfaces and Fano 3-folds", 
Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra vol. 170

provides some answers to Tom's question "What happens to the fundamental group of a singular variety when removing the singular points?"

It appears that the fundamental group of the smooth part can be quite complicate also in simple situations. For instance, one of the results in the paper is the following:

"THEOREM. Let X be a $K3$ surface with at worst Du Val singularities (then X is still simply connected), and let $X^0$ be its smooth part. The number $c$=#(Sing $X$) is bounded by $16$, and if $c=16$ then $\pi_1(X^0)$ is infinite".

So, given for instance a quartic surface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ with $16$ nodes (a Kummer surface) we have

$\pi_1(X)=\{1\}$, but $\pi_1(X^0)$ is infinite!

This follows from the fact that $X^0$ has an étale $\mathbb{Z}_2$-cover $Y^0 \to X^0$, where $Y^0$ is an Abelian surface minus 16 points.

For smaller values of $c$, the group $\pi_1(X^0)$ is finite, but not trivial in general.

In higher dimension, there is the following

"CONJECTURE. Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano $n$-fold. Then the topological fundamental group $\pi_1(V^0)$ of the smooth part $V^0$ of $V$ is finite".

(a normal variety $V$ with at worst log terminal singularities is $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano if, by definition, the anti-canonical divisor $−K_V$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier and ample).